# What is GQL or cloud datastore Count number of rows in PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

In the interest of time, I do mean GQL, But I want in PHP function

`SELECT * FROM Song WHERE composer = 'Lennon, John'`
The following failed

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myEntity`
also the following

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM myEntity
```

or else in Normal Cloud datastore query

As shown in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass#GqlQuery_count 
I can't understand for PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry this is Nosql so it doesn't have Aggregate function